# Intercourse with lactating wife

Tags: sharia

Is it permissible to engage in intercourse with your wife if she is lactating?

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Answer (score 2):

Allah Says in the Holy Quran Chapter 2 Surah Baqarah verse 223:

```
Your wives are as a tilth unto you; so approach your tilth when or how ye will.
```

Islam has allowed the husband and the wife in marriage every possible liberty to enjoy conjugal relations with each other, except three:

It is strictly prohibited to have sexual intercourse with one’s wife during her period of menstruation.

It is strictly prohibited to enter the woman through her anus.

Although there is no specific prohibition mentioned in the Quran and Sunnah, the majority of the scholars in Islam have voiced their opinion against ‘oral’ sex, whereby one touches the other’s private organs with their mouth.

Other than the above three restrictions, there are absolutely no restrictions on how a husband may enjoy his conjugal relations with his wife in the sacred bond of marriage in Islam.  Provided none of the above three restrictions are violated, one may enjoy conjugal relations with one’s wife in any place, at any time, and any how their heart’s desire.

Comment: To be precise, the ruling about oral sex is not that it is _haram_ but that it is _makruh_ (disliked/hated) because of its nature.